# Token Mismatch - USD vs GBP - Cordapp - Kotlin - Blockchain

Tags: kotlin, blockchain, corda

All my tests in IOUStateTests pass except the one where I am writing my 'pay' method. I have written it as below.

I get error as `Token mismatch: USD vs GBP`. By default, does Corda take USD as its currency? As given in the problem statement, one property viz.- 'paid' of the 'class IOUState' initiates in Pounds. I did the same. I have copied it in the 'pay' method inside the class and adding it into the 'paid'. But getting the error above. Please help :)

This is for CorDapp development using Kotlin.

```
data class IOUState(val amount: Amount<Currency>,
                    val lender:Party,
                    val borrower:Party,
                    val paid: Amount<Currency> = POUNDS(0),
                    override val linearId : UniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier()):  LinearState {
    override val participants: List<Party> get() = listOf(lender, borrower)
    fun pay(amountToPay: Amount<Currency>) = copy(paid = paid.plus(amountToPay))

}
```

I expect the method `'pay'` to return the addition of `'paid'` and `'amountToPay'`in Pounds. But I am getting the error that, `'paid '` is in POUNDS and `amountToPay` is in USD. SO, unable to add.

Comment: what code are you passing into the `pay` function? Is the currency the same as the `paid` value in `IOUState`

Comment: @DanNewton This is what I am passing -fun checkPayHelperMethod() {
        val iou = IOUState(10.DOLLARS, ALICE.party, BOB.party)
        assertEquals(5.DOLLARS, iou.pay(5.DOLLARS).paid)
        assertEquals(3.DOLLARS, iou.pay(1.DOLLARS).pay(2.DOLLARS).paid)
        assertEquals(10.DOLLARS, iou.pay(5.DOLLARS).pay(3.DOLLARS).pay(2.DOLLARS).paid)
    }

Answer (score 0):

Your current solution initializes the paid field to zero pounds. The currency token is hard-coded to POUND for the paid field.

This is the reason your code breaks, when any other currency is passed as parameter for the paid method.

In the the first few tests in the [IOUStateTests](https://github.com/corda/corda-training-template/blob/master/kotlin-source/src/test/kotlin/net/corda/training/state/IOUStateTests.kt) class POUND amounts are used. This works just fine with your current code. But as soon as you also execute the later tests, where DOLLAR [Amounts](https://docs.corda.net/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.contracts/-amount/index.html) are used for testing, your code breaks.

You should not hard-code the currency in your code.

A potential solution for the problem is to initialize the paid field based on the passed amount. You can reference the passed amount value when initializing the paid field.

The following worked for me:

```kotlin
@BelongsToContract(IOUContract::class)
data class IOUState(
        val amount: Amount<java.util.Currency>,
        val lender: Party,
        val borrower: Party,
        val paid: Amount<java.util.Currency> = Amount.zero(amount.token),
        override val linearId: UniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier()
    ): ContractState, LinearState {

    override val participants: List<Party> get() = listOf(lender, borrower)

    fun pay(paid: Amount<Currency>) = this.copy(paid = this.paid.plus(paid))
}
```

Instead of hard-coding the Currency token to POUND or DOLLAR; we can use the currency token of the amount parameter.

Using this solution all tests are passing without changing the currencies used in the tests:

[image: Results]

Answer (score -1):

Your paid property in the IOUState you've defined is set to Pounds. The only plausible explanation for why you're getting this error is that you're passing in some Dollar amount to your pay function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, my concern is, how do I define amountToPay in Pounds, so that, the error won't occur.

Comment: In the code you posted in a comment above, just change DOLLARS to POUNDS

Comment: It worked! Thanks :) But, I wanted the 'pay' function to convert the DOLLARS to POUNDS.

Comment: You can do that, but you'd need to create a new function that takes in dollars, pulls in the FX rate for GBP/USD and uses and returns pounds accordingly

Comment: OK. Will try and will revert back to you.